# Git branch affects master

Tags: git, git-branch

I am working on a google maps project on android and i need to update the maps to the new v2 version, thus ive created a branch with

```
git add -u
git commit -m 'xxxyyyzzz'
git checkout -b MapsV2
```

Then i realized i needed to fix something really quick on the master branch so i ran

```
git checkout master
```

only to find out all of my changes in the MapsV2 branch were intact on the master branch after the checkout.

To give some more context, master is our main branch, whilst MapsV2 is the research branch for the new maps API.

What did i do wrong?

Comment: Why did you create the branch after committing?

Comment: Because i commited some changes to master that i wanted to have on the MapsV2 branch as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default `git checkout` will not reset state of your working directory, for this you need to use `git reset --hard` after checkout. Beware, this will reset both your index and working directory and by doing this you can lost all uncommitted changes!

Comment: Alternatively, you could `git stash` on the branch before checking out master.

Comment: That means if i want to swap from branch to branch i have to either stash my work or commit it before resetting? Kind of counter-intuitive but i guess it has its reason

Comment: @Machinarius: Git can only remember what you commit (stashing it is similar to committing, only in a separate storage) -- if you don't commit your changes and change to another branch, how else would you expect git to handle your uncommitted stuff?

Comment: Yes, you are absolutely true. That's why git-stash is here, so you are able to save the changes for later commit when you urgently need to switch to something else.

Answer (score 0):

(I assume that you were on the `master` branch before you started the sequence of command you give.)

You made the commit before you created the new branch. So those changes were made to `master`. You then created the new `MapsV2` branch from `master`, so that branch has the changes as well.

Comment: I may not have been clear enough: after i switched into MapsV2 i made a couple changes, then i switched back into master when they were there

Comment: I see. anydot's answer is correct then. The standard way to deal with your situation is to `git stash` before you switch back to master. This is exactly what `stash` is designed for.